# How to correctly dispose a SensorManager

Tags: java, android

Hey,
I am using a SensorManager in my Android application. I understand that I have to dispose it in some way once the application is closed, because otherwise it would continue to listen to changes. So I tried the following:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        manager.unregisterListener(temp);
    }
```

(when temp was an instance of TempListener extends SensorEventListener, and it was added to the SensorManager manager with manager.registerListener(temp...)). I also tried manager = null, but they all cause me the application to force close. Where am I going wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: You definitely have to unregister any `SensorEventListener` that you may have registered. There is nothing else needed to "dispose a SensorManager". If your `unregisterListener()` call is crashing, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I tried running it with a debugger, but it only shows me that the crash happened at ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(IBinder, boolean, int, boolean) line 3361. I think it has problems with working on applications which use sensors.

Comment: I guarantee you that it is possible to unregister a listener.  See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Sensor/Shaker

Comment: I of course do not doubt it, I simply cannot understand why the code I wrote causes it to force close. Perhaps it shouldn't be in onDestroy, but in a different method?

Comment: the example from commonsware registers a listener in the onCreate and unregisters it at onDestroy (through the Shaker class)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't write super.onDestroy(). Silly me...